# Error in make telegram bot

Tags: c#, telegram, telegram-bot

i have problem in make telegram bot!!!and this is the Error!
`CS0029 Cannot implicitly convert type 'string[][]' to 'NetTelegramBotApi.Types.KeyboardButton[][]`

> Notice : I use C# for making bot!

please help 
thanks

Comment: Can you add more code and explanation ? So far, this is very vague

Comment: It looks like you are attempting to assign an array of string type to an array of KeyboardButton type. They are not same type; this is an invalid conversion. Without a code example of the problem, there isn't much else we can help you with.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Error log only said that you put `string` as `KeyboardButton`, please generate [KeyboardButton](https://core.telegram.org/bots/api#keyboardbutton).

Answer (score -1):

You can use the following code:

```
mainMenu = new ReplyKeyboardMarkup {
  Keyboard = new KeyboardButton[][] {
    new KeyboardButton[] {
      new KeyboardButton("Your Text")
    }
  }
};
```